# AngularJS: Directive isolate scope - scope variable undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Please, can someone explain me, why `attrDir`'s scope variable is visible, and `oneWay`'s not?
I thought that `scope: {}` is isolated as well.

```
angular.module('test', []);

angular.module('test').directive('attrDir', attrDir);

function attrDir(){
    return {

        scope: true,

        link: function(scope){
          scope.hello = 'attrDir';
        }

    };
}

angular.module('test').directive('oneWay', oneWay);

function oneWay(){
    return {

        scope: {
          data: '<?'
        },

        link: function(scope){
          scope.hello = 'oneWay';  
        }

    };
}
```

`hello` will be rendered only in `attr-dir`.

```
<attr-dir>
  <span>{{hello}}</span>
</attr-dir>
<one-way>
  <span>{{hello}}</span>
</one-way>
```

Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/2CM4vVRshWuJvaBj2q8T?p=preview

Thx.

Comment: It should be noted that none of the answers addresses the question correctly.

Comment: Estus is right - `one way !== isolated scopes`.

Comment: @lin, see correct answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42735839/2545680)

Comment: The force is with Kindzuko now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you're observing has nothing to do with `<` binding.

The problem is that the expression `{{hello}}` inside both directives **are not** part of the template of these directives. And for such elements the rules for bindings are different.

Angular automatically creates link functions for `{{hello}}` expressions. But the scopes against which these link functions are evaluated are different in your cases.

What you probably expected is this:

```
            rootScope
         /             \
        /               \
attr-dir-new-scope  one-way-isoloate-scope
      /                   \
     /                     \
{{hello}}               {{hello}}
```

However, according to [this comment in source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2802):

> // We only pass the isolate scope, if the isolate directive has a
>   template, 
> // otherwise the child elements do not belong to the isolate
>   directive.

the real picture is this:

```
             root scope
         /             \    \
        /               \    \
attr-dir-new-scope       \    one-way-isoloate-scope
      /                   \
     /                     \
{{hello}}               {{hello}}
```

So in your example, the first directive `<attr-dir>` doesn't create isolate scope, but creates new scope, so when linking angular passes this new scope both to the linking function of your directive:

```
link: function(scope){
     scope.hello = 'attrDir';
}
```

and to the linking function created for the `{{hello}}` expression. That's why when you add a value in your linking function it's available in the expression linking function.

But your second directive `<one-way>` creates **isolate scope** and according to the comment I mentioned above, the linking function of the directive gets **isolated scope** as it should, but the linking function of the expression receives **different scope** (root scope in your example). So you're adding `hello` value on different scopes. That's why the value is undefined.

Comment: Can you show us how your assumed  `<one-way` directive implements the **isolate scope** using `<?`

Comment: @GangadharJannu, `>?` doesn't implement isolate scope, isolated scope is implemented by specifying object for the `scope` property in directive definition object

Comment: If that is the case what does `<?` means?

Comment: BTW that is not `>?`, OP tried `<?` in his directive

Comment: @GangadharJannu, I don't have time right now. Create a question and I'll provide an answer there later. It's `<`, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L989) in this regex `@&<`. `?` just says that it's optional

Comment: @Maximum I know what `?` means. We can't assume what is there in angular source, however we are answering what OP is asking. In question it is `data: '<?'`

Comment: @GangadharJannu, I used `>?` in my comment by mistake. There is no such binding

Comment: I know there is nothing like `>?`

Answer (score 0):

Both scope: true and scope:{} will create a child scope for the directive. But,

scope:true will prototypically inherit the properties from the parent(say the controller where the directive comes under) where asscope:{} will not inherit the properties from the parent and hence called isolated

As oneWay is an isolated scope directive and  you are not passing the hello, so it is undefined in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If scope is not specified, it is shared scope.
If scope is specified as true, it is inherited scope.
If scope is specified with curly braces, it is isolate scope.

The best way to visualize the scopes is by using console.log statements in your link functions like so,

```
link: function(scope) {          
      scope.hello = 'attrDir';
      console.log('scope in attrDir: ', scope);
    }

    link: function(scope) {          
          scope.hello = 'oneWay';
          console.log('scope in oneWay: ', scope);
        }
```

If you open the developer tools, you will see that the first directive inherits its parent scope in its prototype

```
__proto__:Scope
```

whereas the second one is an object with its own scope (by using curly braces you gave it an isolate scope)

```
__proto__:Object
```

Answer (score -2):

Because you're implementing component bindings in directive.

> The < symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5.

If you want to show the `hello` in `one-way` component you should change the implementation like below:

### HTML

```
 <one-way hello="$ctrl.hello">
      <span>{{$ctrl.hello}}</span>
    </one-way>
```

### JS

```
angular.module('test').component('oneWay', {
  bindings:{
    hello:'='
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.hello = 'oneWay';
  }
});
```

## Demo

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kdw4dY?p=preview)

Comment: So, you are saying that `directive` using `<` becomes component under the hood?

Comment: @Kindzoku. I was saying there is nothing like `<` binding in directive. If you want to use it you have to use it in `component` which is introduced in angular 1.5

Comment: How does this answer the question? Even if  there's no `data: '<?'` binding, it will be the same.

Comment: @estus. OP tried to use `<` which is not presented in directives bindings. so I suggested him to use component if he wants to implement `<` bindings

Comment: @GangadharJannu, your answer is wrong. see correct answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42735839/2545680)

Comment: @Kindzoku,  please see correct answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42735839/2545680)

Comment: @Maximus You've probably explained the concept in another context. Just because you explained in different manner doesn't means other answers are wrong. OP asked *why attrDir's scope variable is visible, and oneWay's not?* and I explained in the context of angular 1.5 component bindings. Because OP is using `<` in directive which it is not all existed, I suggested him to use `<`.

Comment: @all before down voting just mention your context so that I will look into it

Comment: @GangadharJannu, `angular 1.5 component bindings` are applied to **directives templates**, and no directive in OP case uses templates. Besides, `<` symbol is used for directives as well, since component is a directive under the hood. And third, OP uses `1.5` version in his example

Comment: If that is the cause can you show me how we can implement `<` in directives because I'm really not sure about that

Comment: @GangadharJannu, check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/veWzogD94tRSINtDU3uN?p=preview) to see `<` used in directives. Also, you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1281) that component is just a fancy directive.